why does assigning to the ellipsis `... <- 1` not throw an error?
NB: What I do below may not be directly useful. But I would like to understand why R works this way.

The ellipsis (...) has a special meaning in R functions. Evaluating it directly will throw an error.
> ...
Error: '...' used in an incorrect context
> foo <- \(...) return(...)
> b <- foo(a=1)
Error: '...' used in an incorrect context

Interestingly, assigning to it throws no error.
> ... <- 1

For other reserved words like NULL or NA, an error is thrown
NULL <- 1
Error in NULL <- 1 : invalid (do_set) left side assignment

To the R experts: What exactly is happening here? Is there a reason, why the assignment does not throw an error? Is it useful in some way?

I believe ... only purpose is in function argument handling and hence makes only sense to use it wihin function, unlike e.g. NULL it is however not hard coded into R (i.e. you cannot change it). You can thus, because it is not predefined outside the function context, assign it something, but it will not be useful in any way.

Probabaly nobody ever thought some smarty :-) would try this --  but it gets worse!   Check for location:  find('?') shows "?" operator is in utils ,  but utils::? throws the error " unexpected '?' in "utils::?"  "    .    Some operators in R  are a bit funky.

Now that you've tricked me into creating an object named "..."   someone tell me how to remove it!  rm(ls(patt='[.]{2,}',all.names=TRUE)) fails because rm tries to interpret the string "..." found by that ls() call.   OH, thank goodness:  rm("...") does work.

We can "execute" NA and NULL but we cannot "execute" ... without further specification. I think the reason lies somewhere here: ... is defined in a functional environment, both NA and NULL are not.

@CarlWitthoft:  q() should work to clean your workspace, unless you allow it to save things.  If you do that, stop right now.

@user2554330  LOL I would never use the nuclear option :-)

did anyone answer why f <- function(...) return(...); f(1) throws an error but g <- function(...) return(c(...)); g(1) is fine? is it because ... is not a valid expression or more specifically a DOTSXP, a pairlist of promises, while technically is a type of expression, it is not the type of expression that can be used as an argument to return?

@rawr:  I've edited an explanation into my answer.

It isn't a reserved word, it's just a name that is interpreted in a special way.  Reserved words are treated specially by the parser.  Only the code evaluator treats ... specially, it has no syntax implications.
As far as I know, the only way to retrieve a value you assigned to a variable named ... is to use get(), or similar:
... <- 1
...             # gives an error
get("...")      # this is fine
globalenv()$... # so is this

Edited to add:
Regarding the difference between
f <- function(...) return(...)
f(1)

(which throws an error) and
g <- function(...) return(c(...))
g(1)

which is fine:
return() is a primitive function.  They do pretty much what they like with arguments.  What return(arg) does is to evaluate arg in the context where return() is being called, i.e. the function evaluation frame.  Since arg in the f() example is just ..., it's like trying to evaluate ... on its own, and that's not allowed.
You can see the source for the C code implementing return() here:  https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/a87aee1d3a7bec255650bb3aafdd8bd4974bec2f/src/main/eval.c#L3011-L3025  if you want to see the gory details.

Thanks. This is very interesting. Understanding this inspired a rudimentary getter and setter to modify the ... inside a function directly (where needed). So one can modify and pass on the dots to another function directly, instead of using do.call(foo, list(...)). see here
